# 32-bit registers in addressing modes in 64-bit assembly not allowed?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, addressing-mode

What is wrong with the following instruction:

```
movb $0xF, (%ebx)
```

The answer states that `%ebx` cannot be used as an address register. I am new to assembly so can someone explain what this means?

If the instruction was `movb $0xF, (%rbx)` would that have been valid? Also what exactly is an address register? Lastly, does writing brackets around a register directly refer to the memory location the register is pointing to?

Comment: The context must be that it is x86-64. In 64-bit mode, addressing is usually done using full 64 bits, so `%rbx` would work there but your instructional material  says `%ebx` not, as it is only the low 32-bits of `%rbx`. Addressing is done through addressing modes. The purpose of addressing is to locate and access memory, to read or in this case, to write. Processors offer various addressing modes to help compute the memory location to use. Here the addressing mode is register indirect. In that mode, the register's value specifies the memory location of where to write the byte value 0xf.

Comment: *Lastly, does writing brackets around a register directly refer to the memory location the register is pointing to?*  Sort of, though not exactly — it simply specifies the [register indirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Register_indirect) addressing mode; how that is then used depends on the context including whether as first or second operand, as well as what the actual opcode is.

Comment: *Also what exactly is an address register?*  An address register is any register that can be involved in forming the base pointer for an addressing mode.  For x86-64, the general purpose integer registers can be used for addressing, so we don't really call them address registers.  Note that x86 family also has floating point and vector registers that are for different purposes and don't support the notion of being address registers.  On some processors, e.g. mc68k, there is a separation between address and data registers even among the integer registers, so there the term has more meaning.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with `movb $0xf, (%ebx)`<sup>1</sup>.

Even in 64-bit mode it's fine per sè. Surely [x32 programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) won't mind using it and `r/e/bx` can be certainly used as a base register (in fact `bx` is one of the few original registers that could act as a base in 16-bit mode).

My advice is to find a better source for learning.

---

<sup>1</sup>  which is correctly assembled as `67 C6 03 0F` in 64-bit and 16-bit mode and without the address-size override byte (`67`) in 32-bit mode.

Comment: It is true that most programs *shouldn't* use `(%ebx)`, instead use `(%rbx)` because that avoids spending an extra byte of machine-code size on a `67h` address-size prefix.  But you're right, a better guide would have told you that it's allowed but inefficient and truncates your pointer to 32-bit (which might be an error if you didn't want and need that.)